# Hibernate and Oracle DATE column using HQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, date, hql

I have an Oracle database with a DATE column.  A sample value from this column is `15/12/2014 15:20:15` in the format `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS`.

I have this column defined as follows in my java Entity class:

```
@Column(name = "SVC_EVENT_END_DTTM", columnDefinition = "timestamp")
private Date dateTime;
```

The following HQL query works:

```
public List<ServiceEventLogEntity> getServiceEventLogEntries(DateTime from,
        DateTime to) {
    Query query = getSession().createQuery("FROM ServiceEventLogEntity e "
            + "WHERE e.dateTime between :start and :end "
            + "ORDER BY e.dateTime");
    query.setDate("start", from.toDate());
    query.setDate("end", to.toDate());
    query.setMaxResults(100);
    if(to.isBefore(new DateTime())) {
        // Only caching results for queries in the past.
        // Otherwise we could cache incomplete results when 
        // the end of the query range is in the future
        query.setCacheable(true);
    }
    try {
        return (List<ServiceEventLogEntity>) query.list();
    } catch (HibernateException hex) {
        hex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, this only seems to work when the start and end times span a day transition, see the trace messages below:

```
[http-8080-1] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - Sat Dec 13 23:35:00 GMT 2014
[http-8080-1] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [DATE] - Sun Dec 14 00:35:00 GMT 2014
```

I'm guessing that this is due to the fact that my `DATE` objects only represent a day and don't have a time element.  I want to be able to query on minutes/hours not days.  I've tried various approaches such as using `setTimestamp` instead of `setDate` but this just ends up resulting in the query never coming back with results, even in a much narrower window of time (5 minutes).

How can I modify either my entity or my query so I can go to a more granular level to enable me to query by minute or hour instead of day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "SVC_EVENT_END_DTTM")
private Date dateTime;
```

Some javadoc from Temporal source code says:

*[...] This annotation must be specified for persistent fields
or properties of type java.util.Date and
java.util.Calendar [...]*

If you don't need milliseconds, than you can use Oracle's `DATE` type in column (which is up to seconds). When you need millis than you must use Oracle's TIMESTAMP type.

== EDIT ==

Additionaly you should use `query.setTimestamp()` instead of `query.setDate()`. I have checked `org.hibernate.Query` sources and is says:

```
/**
 * Bind the date (time is truncated) of a given Date object 
 * to a named query parameter.
 *
 * @param name The name of the parameter
 * @param date The date object
 */
public Query setDate(String name, Date date);
```

but

```
/**
 * Bind the date and the time of a given Date object to a named query parameter.
 *
 * @param name The name of the parameter
 * @param date The date object
 */
public Query setTimestamp(String name, Date date);
```

Comment: Yeah I originally had that annotation too. It seems to make no difference whether it's there or not.

Comment: I have added some more info. It seems that @Temporal type is important for Hibernate when you use generic `query.setParameter(String name, Object val)`. But you can use `query.setTimestamp` to tell that you want to use temporal=timestamp.

Comment: I have tried numerous combinations and I'm quite certain I've used `setTimestamp` in combination with the `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` annotation to no avail

Comment: I suggest to try one more time with `setTimestamp`. I have checked my old project, where I found several places with hqlquery.setTimestamp and it worked. Sometimes we are sure but accidentally checked other setting that we thought, as I have very often :)

Comment: OK I have tried it, I put `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` on the `dateTime` field in my Entity and I altered the query to use `setTimestamp("start", from.toDate())` and the same for `end` but I have the same issue.  The query executes but never seems to return any results and never throws an error.

Comment: It's as if using `setTimestamp()` actually results in a massive query that is so large the database never completes it...

Comment: The server just sits there with this message in the console `[http-8080-2] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler  - Handling invocation of statement method [executeQuery]
`